# How to handle Warning</b>: oci_connect(): OCI_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO:

Tags: php, oracle, connection

I have created a service that returns a JSON data It was working perfectly but after some time I was getting parsing error. the result was no longer same it added with Warning "your Password expires in 9 Days".

```
try {
    $conn = oci_connect($db_username, $db_password, $tns);
    if (oci_error($conn)) {
        $e = oci_error($conn);
        trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
    }else {
        // Do Operations.
    }
}
```

before:

```
result:
{
[
{sku : "011701000296"
name : "CROWN TOAST BREAD LARGE 950GM"
price : "9.5"
qty : "150"},

{sku : "011701000302"
name : "MODERN ARABIC BREAD BROWN {MEDIUM}"
price : "1.25"
qty : "101"},

{sku : "011701000304"
name : "MODERN MILKY SLICE BREAD"
price : "3.85"
qty : "101"},

{sku : "011701000043"
name : "AL-TAJ ARABIC BREAD LARGE 6S"
price : "2.5"
qty : "101"}]
}
```

The result I am getting Now :

> **Warning**:  oci_connect(): OCI_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO: ORA-28002: the password will expire within 4 days in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Webservices\getupdates.php** on line **27**
>       {"result":[{"sku":"011701000296","name":"CROWN TOAST BREAD LARGE 950GM","price":"9.5","qty":"150"},{"sku":"011701000302","name":"MODERN ARABIC BREAD BROWN {MEDIUM}","price":"1.25","qty":"101"},{"sku":"011701000304","name":"MODERN MILKY SLICE BREAD","price":"3.85","qty":"101"},{"sku":"011701000043","name":"AL-TAJ ARABIC BREAD LARGE 6S","price":"2.5","qty":"101"}]}

I have tried to check the If condition with error but it is not satisfying the condition.

Please help how can I handle this situation and resolve it.

Comment: That's because it isn't an error, it's a warning. They are not treated the same in PHP. Can't you set the password to not expire in Oracle? If you don't the code will still stop working when the password expires.

Comment: I am sure I have to fix password expiration from Oracle, but I want to make my hands dirty with these situations and handling this warning just in case if I have any similar kind of issues to handle.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Have a look at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/659/how-to-get-rid-of-ora-28002-message-the-password-will-expire-within-6-days to remove the expiry date for your account. This helps you in the long-term view, as within the next days, your account might get locked for using that expired password. If you are not able to request a password that will not expire, you should at least renew it within the next four days (as given in the warning)
- Disable printing errors to your page, as no outside user (such as the consumer of your API) should see them. This should be done through setting `display_errors = off` in your `php.ini` settings. But beware, if the password still expires, the warning is only blocked from being printed

Comment: For general background, if the password eventually expires and your app has a GUI (instead of being a webservice), you can prompt the user for a new password and then connect with the second form of [oci_password_change()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-password-change.php).